# css style for input type file which has image

Tags: html, css

I want to leave space among file input which has png browse image.

```
  <input type="text" id="file12" name="file12" size=18 maxlength=500> 
   <div class="upload_wrapper" style="float: left;" id="up0">
  <img src="image/browse.png" style="height:30%,width:40%;"/>
  <input  style="width: 100px;height:10px;" id="uploadbtn4" name="pic[]" type="file" class="upload" name="bfile12" onchange="CopyMe(this, \'file12\');"/>
  </div><br>
```

css code

```
 <style type="text/css">
 input[type='file'] {
 color: transparent;
 float: right;
 margin-right:23%;
 }
 </style>
```

This is working finely for button without image.image upload button is look like as screen shot.[image]

Comment: Can you explain exactly what the problem is? I don't really understand what you mean. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you need to use semicolon instead of a comma while using multiple styling properties like `style="height:30%,width:40%;"` is wrong, should be `style="height:30%;width:40%;"`

Secondly, why don't you use margin in image itself?

```
<img src="image/browse.png" style="height:30%;width:40%;margin:0 23%;"/>
```

---

Finally, I would like to recommend you to use a class in the image and use styling there in your stylesheet:

```
<img src="image/browse.png" class="your_class" />

.your_class{
  height:30%;
  width:40%;
  margin: 0 23%;
}
```